# Regex match commas and periods unless surrounded by digits

Tags: java, regex

I have the regular expression:

`[^\w-,.]|((?<!\d)[,.]`

which matches all non `[\w-,.]` or, using a negative lookbehind, any comma or period not preceded by a digit.

Using java-compatible regex, I need to capture:

- `[^\w,.]`
- `,` unless preceded and followed by a `\d`

  - (eg no capture for `1,2,3` but capture `[\s,]` in `1, 2, 3`)
- `.` unless preceded and followed by a `\d`

  - (eg no capture for `12.32` but capture for `23.`)

My regex gets me close, however, I am not able to capture the commas and periods in the following examples:

- `1.a` (need to capture the period)
- `32, foo` (need to capture comma and whitespace)
- `1.1.` (need to capture the last period)

The following example illustrates example of working and non-working strings to match.

https://regex101.com/r/pWcwXa/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this ?

```
[^\w-,.]|((?<!\d)[,.]|[,.](?!\d))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pWcwXa/3),,, in which I slightly changed your regex only to add the case which `not followed by a digit`